# problem in delegate declaration and its invocation

Tags: c#

When I try to call the event `myevent` in the function `fire`, it gives compiler error as

> delegate mydelegate does not take 0 arguments.

if i try to give arguments in calling myevent as

```
myevent(this);
```

it again shows error as it does not take 1 parameters. what parameters am i supposed to give in the calling `myevent`? Here's the program code:

```
namespace useofdelegates
{
    public class Class1
    {   int i;
        public delegate void mydelegate(object sender,EventArgs e);
        public event mydelegate myevent;
        public void fire()
        {
            myevent(this); // *** shows compiler error ***
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error is because you are using a delegate with two parameters and calling it with one.

The simple solution is

```
myevent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

The more regular (and thread-safe) solution, which I think you're getting confused with is

```
OnMyEvent(EventArgs.Empty);

// and then later

public void OnMyEvent(EventArgs args)
{
    mydelegate handler = myevent;
    if(handler != null) handler(this, args);
}
```

The reason for doing it this way is that you should always make sure that there is at least one handler attached to the event.  There is a small chance that the handler can be detached between checking for null and calling the handler, so it's good to pass it on to another variable which it cannot be detached from before checking for null.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in 2 parameters. the first one being the source of the event. In your example "this" would work. The second one being of type EventArgs or a realted subclass. You can also pass EventArgs.Empty is you do not wish to pass any event especific information to the event handler.

So your method would look like this

```
fire(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

or

```
fire(this, new MyCustomEVentArgs());
```

Here is an MSDN link with an example of using events http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(VS.71).aspx

and nother one on creating custom EventArg subclasses to use in your handler. http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Creating-Custom-Delegates-and-Events-in-C-sharp/

Answer (score 0):

Just create an empty EventArgs I guess.

```
myevent(this, new EventArgs());
```

Note, here is the full code:

```
namespace useofdelegates
{
    public class Class1
    {
        int i;
        public delegate void mydelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);
        public event mydelegate myevent;
        public void fire()
        {
            myevent(this, new EventArgs()); // *** shows compiler error ***
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @smriti, what's the compiler error?   The code compiles on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `mydelegate` to require an `object` and an `EventArgs`, so you have to pass these in. Of course, you don't have declare your delegate with these arguments. You could just declare it thus:

```
public delegate void mydelegate();
```

or just pass `this` as the sender:

```
public delegate void mydelegate(object sender);
```